# IE 10 isn't showing images when viewed locally

Tags: html, image, internet-explorer-10

I try to view an htm page locally (on my laptop) in IE 10 and none of the images appear. However, if I go to the image url itself, it shows fine. For example, if I go to the URL "C:\Users\Angie\Desktop\pdb\ROTE - Main Menu.htm", images like this:

```
<IMG SRC="graphics/LogoSm2.gif" STYLE="Margin-top: 0pt; margin-bottom: 0pt" width="71" height="67">
```

do not show, but if I go directly to the image, "C:\Users\Angie\Desktop\pdb\graphics\LogoSm2.gif", it shows.

Can anyone help please?

Edit: RESOLVED. FIGURED IT OUT! It was a stupid oversight on my part. The file had a .htm extension from where I copied it, but I had to change it to .html to view locally. :-P It works with the original relative links. Thanks everyone who tried to help.

Comment: Works in other browsers btw.

Answer (score 1):

You're using a relative path, which means the server checks from the directory it is in.  You could traverse all the way to the file, but that's not really recommended.  Add the image into your `web-app/images` directory and grab it that way.

[This site](http://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/ResourceUrlProblems) may help regarding some resource resolution, although it's a little unclear from your question which server/language you're using.

Comment: I tried it with the full path too, no luck. I should've mentioned that. Thanks. (file:///C:/Source/ROTE/WWW/Graphics/LogoSm2.gif)

Comment: @user3310886 Well that's not the right syntax, but it's really not the right way to do it anyway.  When you load a website onto another machine, it won't have the same path (there will be no "Angie" folder).  So you should really look into moving your resources into web-app/images.

Comment: I've tried a few different syntaxes, that was one suggested by someone else. I'm not having problems when it is on a server (with the existing relative link), just local. And I DO see the image when I go to "C:\Users\Angie\Desktop\pdb\graphics\LogoSm2.gif" in the address bar. Just not when I hit the page locally. What's web-app/images?

Comment: Are you just editing an HTML page, or are you building a website with a server?  The server docs should describe in detail how to serve resources.

Comment: Server is fine. I copied the file and images (graphics) folder and associated css file to my machine. I just want to change some text, add a link, to take a screen shot for a mockup, that's all. So, I don't care about anything except getting the images to show locally.

Comment: It is just plain html, nothing dynamic. I don't understand why the images won't show, no matter what path I use for them. I tried putting the image in the same directory as the file, still won't show. BUT, it will show if I view that image direct.

Comment: This doesn't: C:\Users\Angie\Desktop\pdb\page.htm

Comment: FIGURED IT OUT! It was a stupid oversight on my part. The file had a .htm extension from where I copied it, but I had to change it to .html to view locally. :-P It works with the original relative links. Thanks everyone who tried to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to

```
src="/graphics/LogoSm2.gif"
```